# capistrano 3 Don't know how to build task 'deploy:updated'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano3

Capistrano fails upon `cap staging deploy`

```
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:updated'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@theapp/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:5:in `before'
```

Capfile requires in order: `require 'capistrano/bundler' require 'capistrano/rails' require 'capistrano/rvm'`

```
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-1.9.3-p484'

require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'
```

I realize there is a release version issue on rvm between 125 locally and 484 remotely.  However I'm not certain this is the cause. 
/deploy/staging.rb states

```
set :stage, :staging
role :app, %w{theapp.domain.tld}
role :web, %w{theapp.domain.tld}
role :db,  %w{theapp.domain.tld}

server '4.44.444.44', user: 'me', roles: %w{web app}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well yes, the sequence must be respected.  What follows overcomes the blockage:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

The default set-up offered on creation of capfile alludes to this, but yours truly decide on doing it his way...